# How to call a method once a component is rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, lifecycle

I have a parent component that conditionally renders two components.  Once I am done entering data in the first component, I click done and then render the second component.  I want the second component to only then parse all the data I entered in the first component.

Im a little confused which lifecycle method I am supposed to be using.

componentdidupdate will not be called unless the state of the second component is updated, correct?  And componentdidmount will be called before I have finished entering data into the first component, since it is already inserted into the tree (although not rendered yet conditionally)?

Comment: Is there no way for the data introduced to be hold by the parent component state? You would just need to handle that to the second component through props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a the useEffect and set the component as a dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
...
}, [yourcomponentStateValue]);
```